# Starling didnt launch

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I follow the tutorials from Hemanth Sharma and when i try to debug my project 
i receive the follow errors

[SWF] C:/Users/savvas/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/newStarling/bin-debug/newStarling.swf - 373,759 bytes after decompressionReferenceError: Error #1069: Property profile not found on flash.display3D.Context3D and there is no default value.

[Starling] Context ready. Display Driver: OpenGL (Standard Constrained)
    at starling.rendering::Painter/configureBackBuffer()[C:\Users\savvas\Downloads\starling-2.1\starling\src\starling\rendering\Painter.as:226]
    at starling.core::Starling/updateViewPort()[C:\Users\savvas\Downloads\starling-2.1\starling\src\starling\core\Starling.as:474]
    at starling.core::Starling/initialize()[C:\Users\savvas\Downloads\starling-2.1\starling\src\starling\core\Starling.as:352]
    at starling.core::Starling/onContextCreated()[C:\Users\savvas\Downloads\starling-2.1\starling\src\starling\core\Starling.as:584]

Anyone who know what this errors are?

Answer (score 0):

This page http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/faq.html states that FB 4.7 comes with Flash Player 11.4, while **Context3D.profile** property is supported by Flash Player 12 (read here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Context3D.html#profile).

In order to use latest Starling release you are required to build your application with up-to-date AIR SDK: https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html